# HTTP-запрос в приложении на React Native

Tags: ajax, http, react-native, fetch

Мне необходимо получит json по http в приложении на React Native. Получить ответ с данными надо именно с *http*, не с *https*.

Для создания проектов и проверки работы приложений использую Expo.

Когда я делаю такое:

> fetch('http://mydomain.com/somefile.json').then(response => ...)

Я получаю блокировку по причине cors.

Есть какой-то способ решить эту проблему? Есть ли какие-то плагины или конфигурации метода fetch (или в работе с XHR), чтобы получить нужный json, а не ошибку о блокировке cors?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на русскоязычный Stack Overflow, переведите свой вопрос, чтоб он соответствовал тематике сайта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему можно решить добавив в заголовки ответа `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, если у Вас есть доступ к бекенду http://mydomain.com

Больше информации о CORS: https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#neprostye-zaprosy

Похожая проблема и её решение(англ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962529/combine-nodejs-react-native-axios-cors

Comment: Спасибо огромное.